# Which property is used to determin whether to allow forwarding an event message in graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I get a Message or Event object, I don't see any property that seems to be related to AllowForward. Tried both v1.0 and beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strongly typed property so you need to use the Extended property for this eg to send a Meeting with no forward

```html
{
   "subject": "My event",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-10-13T04:55:36.463Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-10-20T04:55:36.463Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"blah@domain.com",
        "name": "gs"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "PropertyId": "Boolean {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name DoNotForward",
            "Value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then to retrieve that property with an event use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter%20%3D%20(id%20eq%20'Boolean%20%7B00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046%7D%20Name%20DoNotForward'))
```